# Capture particular area image and remove unwanted space using camera in android application

Tags: android, camera, imageview, overlay

I want to Capture particular area image and remove unwanted space using camera in android application. and then this image set to imageview[image]

I want to capture only inside
 that white rectangle image.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your question is "how do I do this?", then please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you want to use a built-in camera application via ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent, you cannot manipulate the UI, but some devices provide "com.android.camera.action.CROP" intent that can be used to choose a predefined area of an image. If you are using a "custom camera" in your app, then cropping can be performed in onPictureTaken() callback. There are some libraries that can help, see https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html